# Ambiguous multiple choice question

Tags: calculus

So the question is if $f'(c)$ does not exist and $f(x)$ is continuous then $f(x)$ may have

*a*) a local extremum at $x=c$
*b*) a point of inflection at $c$
*c*) neither *a* nor *b* is possible
*d*) both *a* or *b* are possible

I know *a* is not possible because $f'(c)$ would have to equal to $0$. But is it required that the first derivative to exist to have a point of inflection.

Comment: That's not correct, actually: local extrema must happen where $f'(x)=0$ *or where $f'(x)$ is undefined*. Take $f(x)=|x|$ at $x=0$. for example.

Comment: @GregMartin so local extrema can exist when f'c = dne?

Comment: Check with your textbook or course notes to see the *precise* definition of point of inflection. Avoid writing $f'(c)=dne$, which is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the example $$f(x) = |x|, \quad c = 0.$$  Then $f'(0)$ does not exist because $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} = 1,$$ but $$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} = -1.$$  Yet $f(0) = 0$ is a local (and global) extremum because for all $x \in \mathbb R$, $f(x) \ge 0$ with equality attained at $x = 0$.

Now consider the example $$f(x) = x^{1/3}, \quad c = 0.$$  Then $$f'(x) = \frac{1}{3} x^{-2/3}$$ and $f'(0)$ does not exist.  Yet $x = 0$ is an inflection point because $$f''(x) = -\frac{2}{9} x^{-5/3}$$ which is negative for $x > 0$ and positive for $x < 0$.